# Can you play trump if trump hasn't been played and you have action cards in Rage?

Tags: rage

1. Is it true you can’t lead a trump card unless trump has already been played, or all you have in your hand are trump cards?
2. Can you play an “Out Rage” card on top of an “Out Rage” card?
3. Can you play a “Change Rage” card on top of an “Out Rage” card?
4. Say a player has two action cards, one trump card and trump hasn’t been played yet. Can they play their trump card, or do they have to play an action card?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your questions! In accordance with site policy, please split this into four separate posts with only one question each (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) for reasons).

Answer (score 1):

1. No.
2. Yes, but it would have no effect.
3. Yes.
4. [Has its own question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38129/playing-trump-in-rage?rq=1) (asked two hours after yours, but separate questions are better)

[PDF of the rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/rage.pdf)