# Playing Trump in Rage

Tags: rage

If a player has two action cards and one trump card and trump hasn’t been played yet, can they play their trump card or do they have to play an action card?

Answer (score 1):

If you can follow suit, you must. Otherwise you can play any card you want.

In this situation, you can play any of your three cards. It doesn't matter whether anyone has played a trump or not *unless* it was the first suit that was played (trump was led) in which case you'd have to follow suit.

[PDF of the rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/rage.pdf)